# How do i call an instance made in one button from another button in Java

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I'm trying to call the instance of `RSA()` made in `btnNewButton` from another button which is  `btnNewButton_1`

How can i do this or is it even possible?

Here is the code.

```
//ENCRYPT BUTTON
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String num1;

                try{
                    RSA rsa = new RSA();
                    num1 =(textFieldToEncrypt.getText());
                    byte[] encrypted = rsa.encrypt(num1.getBytes());
                    byte[] decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted);
                    textFieldEncStrByte.setText(bytesToString(encrypted));
                    textFieldDecrypted.setText(new String(decrypted));

                }//close try
                catch (Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid Text");         
                }//close catch
            }//close public void
        });//close button

        //DECRYPT BUTTON
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num1;

                try{
                    num1 =(textFieldEncStrByte.getText());
                    byte[] decrypted = decrypt(num1.getBytes());

                    textFieldDecrypted.setText(bytesToString(decrypted));

                }//close try
                catch (Exception e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid Text");         
                }//close catch
            }//close public void
        });//close button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not as it is. This is because Java has [Scoping](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). What you need to do is increase the scope of the variable so that it can be accessed from both methods. Namely, by making it *global*.

```
private RSA rsa = new RSA();

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // use rsa.
}

btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    // use rsa.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it in a class Field, like this

```
class Foo {
  static RSA myRSA;

  public void buidGui() {
    //...
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
       myRSA = ...;
    }
    ActionListener al2 = new ActionListener() {
       if (myRSA != null) // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping problem- you can't share your RSA vriable if it's defined as a local variable inside your method.

To share, please move it to be an instance variable, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private RSA ras = new RSA();

    public void initGui(){
       btnNewButton.addActionListener(){
            .... // this code can use 'ras'
       }
       btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(){
            .... // this code can use 'ras'
       }

    }

}
```

In more detail, your actionListeners are Inner (and anonymouse) classes, meaning they have access to fields of the containing class (MyClass)